# https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text is not readable by black copper 1d barcode scanner

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, google-fonts

i am stucking in problem i have designed application in asp.net and i have use

"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text"

and it works fine [It works fine when showing in browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0RaU.png)

but when i use black copper 1d barcode scanner it is not reading the barcode
what i m doing wring please help me out

thanks
asad

this barcode scanner i am using
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlmGZ.jpg)

Comment: Why not print the barcode with normal code39 instead of extended text? Alternatively, please look for a configuration barcode that changes to code 39 extended text mode.

Comment: you are saying that like this: body {

            font-family: Code39;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

Comment: are you putting the asterisk before and after?
For example if the barcode is going to be "555" then it should be "\*555\*"  minus the quotes

Answer (score 0):

Barcodes need to render as monochrome black/white images.  Fonts on the other hand render anti-aliased, meaning up to 256 level grayscale. If you copy your barcode into an image editor and zoom in, you will see that the black bars do not have sharp edges - they are blurry.  Part of the the blurriness is also caused by the "cleartype-style" sub-pixel rendering that most font engines use.

You will be better off if you can render the barcode as an image, where you have pixel-level control.

Comment: so you are saying that should i have to use it as a images?? in gif??

Comment: Yes, generate the barcode as an image (png or gif - do not use a lossy format such as jpeg).  You will likely need a barcode generation package for asp.net.

Comment: @Assad Ali , Perhaps it has little to do with lossless, and gradation adjustment and anti-aliasing are more important. It would be nice if we could avoid using functions such as contour edge adjustment with the goal of making it a 1bpp monochrome BMP. I'm not sure if it works with ASP.NET, but if you search, you'll find a library like this, but there are many others. [BarcodeLib 2.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BarcodeLib/), [NetBarcode 1.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetBarcode/)